# Small vs Large image (when repeating)

Tags: html, image, repeat

I'm making a bar (like an hr) that will be spanning across the webpage.  Out of curiosity, would it not be best to create the smallest image possible to repeat on the X axis **or** would it be best to make the image semi-wide already so that it doesn't have to repeat too many times?

Comment: What are you trying to optimize? I believe that neither tax the CPU much (read: nearly not at all), and often, because it is so light on the processor, it's generally ideal to minimize size for bandwidth purposes. Honestly, a styled `<hr>` would perform better than an image, if at all possible, since it cuts out the need for an extra HTTP request.

Comment: @Nightfirecat  Well, the normal `<hr />` isn't enough contrast from the background to provide me with what I need.  So, creating a 1x3 image and a 100x3 image doesn't really change the speed at all?

Comment: You can change the color, by just adding a style - the default style for the `<hr />` tag is a 0-height, 1-px-border block element. Just change the border style, and you'll have exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the bar as small as possible. It takes more time to download than it does to render usually. In today's world is doesn't matter as much, though. If you want to make it render faster, I would use something around 100px width or so.  Either way it's not a big deal with the speed of the modern internet and processor.

Use border if you can avoid images.

Comment: Well I'd recommend 1px.  If you think that the rendering is taking too long (which it really shouldn't), then increase it to 100px or so.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the speed issue is going to be the http requests not the amount of times an image is used repetitively. If it's a smaller image, less to download and quicker to view.

With that said, if you want to replicate a `<hr/>` try using a div and border with `outset/inset`;

Comment: ...or just use a `<hr />`, which can have its border styled? HTML _is_ supposed to be semantic, after all.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for the reference for backup but I read that 10x10 or 20x20 is preferable to 1x1 because the blocksize of the HTTP response would result in roughly the same download time and the bigger image is quicker for the browser to lay out.

Comment: What about 20x3?  I'm sure it follows by the same concept?